# Is Pick's formula true for a general (non-integer-vertices) lattice?

Tags: integer-lattices

Does [Pick's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) hold for non-integer lattices (nodes with non-integer coordinates)?

I heard that it holds for any lattice (given lattice is: we take two groups of parallel lines and intersect them - so we have a lattice based by a fundamental parallelogramm) - nodes of such lattice need not be integer numbers. The formula is the same but if it gives number 7 it means "7 times the area of a fundamental parallelogramm of that lattice"

Comment: Seems reasonable. You could take a proof of Pick for the usual lattice, and see whether it goes through for the general lattice. Earlier related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768/picks-theorem-on-a-triangular-or-hex-grid

Comment: I think the general lattice is done in https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.04808 although all the diagrams are for the square lattice. Why not have a look, and report back?

Comment: Had a look yet?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson It didn't clarify anything for me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'll try to have another look, though it won't be for a couple of days.